# Get running processes from a container without exec

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have 3 pods running in a cluster and each pod has 8 containers inside which a process is running.
I need the list of all processes running in all containers without having to exec into each container and execute ps command.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: The processes will all be visible on the host - not sure how easily identifiable they are though.  Why can't you exec?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the process of fetching the processes. Using exec and ps on each container in each pod is taking time. I looking for a way to optimize this.

Comment: If you cannot get granular enough information via `ps` on the host, I think you're probably out of luck.

Comment: Can you run _one_ process to a container, and _one_ container to a pod?  That would simplify management questions like this.

Comment: One process to a container I'd agree with - there should really only ever be one main process. multiple containers in a pod is a perfectly reasonable thing to do, although 24 would probably be a few too many!

Answer (score -1):

Creating a script would be able to get processes in a pod,

Steps

1. Create a loop which gets all three pod names in a cluster.
2. Create a loop to go through all the three pods, and get all the container names.
3. Create a loop to then run the `docker exec` command on each container to get the process running on each container.

Comment: OP has explicitly stated that they don't want to use `kuebctl exec` (but not really why)

Comment: So you do not want to use `docker exec` either?